# robocopy powershell progress bars with multiple lines

Tags: windows, powershell

I have a quick question with regards to robocopy.....when i run the below command in cmd prompt i get the % complete in one line...mean the % bar progresses...

robocopy \network_drve\soft\ C:\Users\test\Downloads file.iso

but when i run the same command thru powershell i get whole bunch of progress bar .... 100's of lines....i understand that powershell console and command prompt are 2 different things but how i can avoid getting output like below in powershell?

```
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
 99.9%
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the /NP switch.

This will turn off the progress updates and should keep that from displaying.  You'll also see similar results in CMD.exe if you pipe the robocopy output into a text file.